# How to rename Java's thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Here is an example created from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTandThread.htm

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;


public class MultiThread extends Shell {

    Button btnNewButton = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Display display = Display.getDefault();
            MultiThread shell = new MultiThread(display);
            shell.open();
            shell.layout();
            while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
                if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                    display.sleep();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the shell.
     * @param display
     */
    public MultiThread(Display display) {
        super(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);


        btnNewButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                applicationThread.start();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(86, 47, 68, 23);
        btnNewButton.setText("New Button");
        createContents();
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the shell.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        setText("SWT Application");
        setSize(450, 300);

    }

    @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {
        // Disable the check that prevents subclassing of SWT components
    }


    final Runnable print = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          System.out.println("Print from thread: \t" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    };

    final Thread applicationThread = new Thread("currentThread") {
        public void run() {
          System.out.println("Hello from thread: \t" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
          getDisplay().syncExec(print);
          System.out.println("Bye from thread: \t" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
      };

}
```

My question is: why IllegalThreadStateException occur on second click on button? Is it because second click creates a thread with same name as previous? How can I avoid that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use Below code to set threads Name

```
Thread.currentThread().setName("Hello");
```

Comment: As you asked "How to rename Java's Thread" I told you how to rename.

Comment: But for your problem Create a separate class for Thread and start it in Constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are starting a thread again without instantiating an object of thread which will result an java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException..
for e.g if you start an thread by instantiating and call start to start executing a thread. Again if you call thread.start will leads to java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException..
The same thing you are trying to achieve in your code.
once your button is clicked you are executing an thread and starting the thread again by calling thread.start()..

For every button click you should start a new thread() by instantiating object of thread.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation of `Thread.start`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--):

> #### throws
>
> IllegalThreadStateException - if the thread was already started.

You are not creating a new thread with the same name, you are calling `start()` on the same thread again and get what the documentation promised you.

It seems, whoever made that example did not consider the possibility that a user clicks a button more than once…

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't start same thread twice: check [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start())

> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.